# How to set default value to region(state) in checkout page magento 2.1..?

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, default-values, regions

I need to set a default value for the region(state) in the checkout page.

tried it using jQuery. it's showing the value the field but it's not saving.

```
require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){

    setInterval(function () {

        if($('input[name="city"]').val() != 'Perth')
        {

           $('input[name="city"]').val("Perth");
           $('input[name="city"]').attr('readonly',true);
           $('input[name="city"]').trigger('keyup');
           $('input[name="region"]').val("WA");
           $('input[name="region"]').attr('readonly',true);
           $('input[name="region"]').trigger('keyup');

        }

        },3000);

});
```

https://prnt.sc/i1jvx6

when I click save it not saving the region(state)

https://prnt.sc/i1jwgf

can anyone help me? it's urgent

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the second screenshot, it shows as Perth.

Comment: Thats the city name , region is not showing "WA"

Comment: You can set default values using `CheckoutConfig` in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use jquery .live() function

like;

```
$('input[name="city"]').live('change', function() {


if($('input[name="city"]').val() != 'Perth')
        {

           $('input[name="city"]').val("Perth");
           $('input[name="city"]').attr('readonly',true);
           $('input[name="city"]').trigger('keyup');
           $('input[name="region"]').val("WA");
           $('input[name="region"]').attr('readonly',true);
           $('input[name="region"]').trigger('keyup');

        }

}
```

Comment: its not Working..

Answer (score 0):

```
require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){

    setInterval(function () {

        if($('input[name="city"]').val() != 'Perth')
        {

           $('input[name="city"]').val("Perth");
           $('input[name="city"]').attr('readonly',true);
           $('input[name="city"]').trigger('keyup');

        }

        },3000);
   setInterval(function () {
    if($('input[name="region"]').region() != 'WA')
        {

           $('input[name="region"]').val("WA");
           $('input[name="region"]').attr('readonly',true);
           $('input[name="region"]').trigger('keyup');

        }

        },3500);

});
```

Not sure if this will work, but try to trigger both of them separately. Or load the bigger entity first, by reversing the 3500, and 3000 values.

Comment: it's not working

Comment: Can you share if you are getting any errors in logs?

Comment: No error, in default checkout its triggering the value and saving it ..i am using Mageplaza One step checkout in that its not saving the default value

Comment: I think the extension you are using has some overridden files above default checkout so you need to check which files are loading and place your code at a proper location. This is more of an extension specific requirement

Comment: Hello @SUBINCHANDRAN , I am also using Mageplaza OSC & it's not working, You found any solution?